# Javascript regex for UK mobile

Tags: javascript, regex

currently I am doing this

```
phone_number.match(/^((\+44\s?|0)7([45789]\d{2}|624)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})$/);
```

The above works good in most cases.  Things like the following are valid

> 07714000000
>   +447714000000

However, I also want to allow the 44 without the + e.g.

> 447714000000

I have tried adding a ? between the + and 44 which works for an online tester, but not when I do it via javascript.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

**Update**
I am using this in JQuery Validation plugin, this is the code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('mobileUK', function(phone_number, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^((\+?44\s?|0)7([45789]\d{2}|624)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})$/);
}, 'Please specify a valid mobile number');
```

It works as normal without the ?, but doesnt match just 44.

Comment: Seems fine in the JavaScript mode of [this online tester](https://regex101.com/r/wZ2qB4/1)?  Can you show your actual JavaScript code?

Comment: As long as you've escaped the `\+?`, no reason you can't add a quantifier.

Comment: You have to get rid of the anchors `^$`

Comment: Definitely works [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV1eX6/). It must be something else. As indicated, please add in some more code.

Comment: I have updated the op

Comment: `'447714000000'.match(/^(\+?44\s?|0)7([45789]\d{2}|624)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/)` works fine for me (I removed additional brackets, but the original also worked)

Comment: Also, you should allow `0044`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you wrote is correct.

However, you should probably allow spaces anywhere in the string. The safest way is to strip all non-numeric characters (which also means you don't have to check for `+`).

### Example

```js
var mobileNumberRegex = /^(?:(?:00)?44|0)7(?:[45789]\d{2}|624)\d{6}$/;
if (phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '').test(mobileNumberRegex)) alert('Phone number is valid!');
```

*Note: The above regular expression also accepts numbers formatted as `00447714000000`.*